# TextBox not stretching horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml

**I am unable to stretch the textbox horizontally fit its container.**

NOTE:

- I do set the HorizontalAlignment property.
- I also tried binding the width of the textbox to its containers width.

Neither worked for me.

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleLines}" Background="Black" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext.Command, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         TextChanged="OnTextChanged" KeyDown="OnKeyDown" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5" Background="Black" Foreground="LightGray"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Try HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the the ListView.  Again on the the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [`ListView.HorizontalContentAlignment` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Stretch` instead. From the linked page:

> ... you can set the HorizontalContentAlignment property to Stretch, which stretches the child element to fill the allocated space of the parent element

---

You must have misunderstood the answer, because it certainly does stretch each item across the entire width of the `GridView`. Try this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleLines}" 
    Background="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="Some simple text" Background="White" 
                Foreground="LightGray"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I originally had it applied to the textbox and not the ListView. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should set the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` of the `ListView` 
[image]

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource viewmodel}}" Background="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Background="Green" Foreground="White" Text=""  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```